# MySQL Table structure when using a meta table

Tags: mysql

Just trying to figure out the best structure for my application.

I have a customer table with 6-7 columns (things like email, name etc)
and I have a customer meta table (meta_key, meta_value, fk_customerID)
which will hold data that isn't relevant for more than about 300 of 10,000 records - that's why I thought to store it in a meta table.

the issue is, when I run a query to LEFT JOIN all the results for searching etc, the query takes an unacceptable time to execute. It can be up to 10 seconds on my local machine.

Do you think it would be better to scrap the meta table, and store it as column data?

I'm trying to ascertain when to use a meta table, when it appears that using it to join and search on all data is an execution time nightmare!

`SELECT users.email, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.p_suburb, users.ph_mobile, users.referral_source, users.registered, usermeta.meta_value as company_name FROM users LEFT JOIN usermeta ON  users.id = usermeta.user_id and usermeta.meta_key='company_name'`

Comment: Please add result of show create table <tablename> for both tables so we can see indexes etc, sample data would also be useful as would an explanation of why you though a meta table would be useful.